# T-SQL `FOR JSON` on single delimited column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a single column in SQL Server 2008 queried through SQL Server 2017 (No support for `OPEN_JSON` in compatibility mode, only `FOR JSON`) that has values like the following.

```
A.1
A.2
B.1
AB.12
```

And I'm trying to use `FOR JSON AUTO` to return objects like the following.

```json
{
   "A": {
    1: true,
    2: true
   }
}
```

OR

```json
{
   "ID": {
      "A": [1,2],
      "B": [1]
   }
}
```

I've figured out my best bet for separating the values is probably `PARSENAME(ID,1)` but I'm not sure how to use that as the key name in a `FOR JSON`.
Something like.

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 PARSENAME(ID,2) as PARSENAME(ID,1)
FROM [SERVER1].[DB1].[SCHEMA1].[TABLE1] a
FOR JSON PATH
```

### UPDATE

Since I found that `PARSENAME` goes in reverse, I've gotten the following query to get the results in a proper order and separated into columns, though I'm still not sure how to get the JSON from this.

```sql
SELECT
CASE 
      WHEN PARSENAME(ID,3) IS NOT NULL THEN PARSENAME(ID,3)
      WHEN PARSENAME(ID,2) IS NOT NULL THEN PARSENAME(ID,2)
      WHEN PARSENAME(ID,1) IS NOT NULL THEN PARSENAME(ID,1)
      ELSE NULL
END AS a,
CASE 
      WHEN PARSENAME(ID,3) IS NOT NULL THEN PARSENAME(ID,2)
      WHEN PARSENAME(ID,2) IS NOT NULL THEN PARSENAME(ID,1)
      ELSE NULL
END AS b,
CASE 
      WHEN PARSENAME(ID,3) IS NOT NULL THEN PARSENAME(ID,1)
      ELSE NULL
END AS c
FROM [SERVER1].[DB1].[SCHEMA1].[TABLE1]

Just results in 
a  |  b  |  c
--------------
A  |  1  | null
A  |  2  | null
B  |  1  | null
AB |  12 | null
```

Comment: Found an issue with `PARSENAME` it will split in reverse order so if the extension is null it will parse it as the other column.

Comment: What will be the output, if you have `a`, `b` and `c` parts in your data (as in the updated question)? And will `AB.12` become `"AB": [12]`? Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov The `FOR JSON AUTO` or `PATH` output is just `[{ "a":"A", "b":"1" }, { "a":"A", "b":"2" }, { "a":"B", "b":"1" }]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the next approach may help you to find an appropriate solution to your problem. I don't think, that you can generate a `JSON` output with variable keys using only `FOR JSON PATH` or `FOR JSON AUTO`, but if you use SQL Server 2017, you may try to generate the ouput using a combination between `JSON_MODIFY()`, `FOR JSON PATH` and string manipulations:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   ID nvarchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO Data 
   (ID)
VALUES
  ('A.1'),
  ('A.2'),
  ('B.1'),
  ('AB.12')
```

Statement:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{}'
;WITH ParsedCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      LEFT(ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) - 1) AS a,
      TRY_CONVERT(int, RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('.', ID))) AS b
   FROM Data      
)
SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, CONCAT('append $.', a), b)   
FROM ParsedCTE

SELECT JSON_QUERY(@json) AS ID
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Output:

```
{"ID":{"A":[1,2],"B":[1],"AB":[12]}}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, thanks. I had two part values as an example, but now I'm trying to use it with three part values, where the third array of properties of the second is optional. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer does answer the exact question I initially asked, so it's still correct. But here's what I found using it.
First, if you have numeric values, you'll need to include quotes on either side in a concat statement.
Second, to get it working, I had to include the `lax` option to `JSON_MODIFY` so it ignores non-existent paths. 
And this is the script I ended up with to convert the three-value delimited column to nested objects:

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{}'
;WITH ParsedCTE AS (
   SELECT
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID) = 0
            THEN ID
            ELSE LEFT(ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) - 1)
            END
      AS a
   FROM [SERVER].[DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]
)

SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, CONCAT('lax $."', a, '"'), JSON_QUERY(N'{}'))
FROM ParsedCTE

;WITH ParsedCTE AS (
   SELECT
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID) = 0
            THEN ID
            ELSE LEFT(ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) - 1)
            END
      AS a,
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID) = 0
                  THEN null
            WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1) = 0
                  THEN RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('.', ID))
            ELSE SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1, LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('.', ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1))
            END
      AS b
   FROM [SERVER].[DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]
   WHERE 
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID) = 0
                  THEN null
            WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1) = 0
                  THEN RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('.', ID))
            ELSE SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1, LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('.', ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1))
            END IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, CONCAT('lax $."', a, '"."', b, '"'), JSON_QUERY(N'{}'))
FROM ParsedCTE

;WITH ParsedCTE AS (
   SELECT
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID) = 0
            THEN ID
            ELSE LEFT(ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) - 1)
            END
      AS a,
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID) = 0
                  THEN null
            WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1) = 0
                  THEN RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('.', ID))
            ELSE SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1, LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('.', ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1))
            END
      AS b,
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID) = 0
                  THEN null
            WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1) = 0
                  THEN null
            ELSE RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('.', ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1))
            END
       AS c
   FROM [SERVER].[DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]
   WHERE 
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID) = 0
                  THEN null
            WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1) = 0
                  THEN null
            ELSE RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('.', ID, CHARINDEX('.', ID) + 1))
            END IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, CONCAT('lax $."', a, '"."', b, '"."', c, '"'), 'true')
FROM ParsedCTE

SELECT JSON_QUERY(@json) AS ID
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

I tried to get it all done in a single CTE recursive statement, but that always overwrites objects since it hasn't instantiated the parents as path-able objects.
So in order to accomplish this, I had to re-modify the JSON for each level I wanted to define.

Unfortunately this resulted in a **~4s** run time. So this is definitely not suitable for real-time data, I'm now thinking about implementing a cache on my backend server to reduce this impact.

### Another Update

I went ahead and went back to something more like the original answer's script since it has a shorter (but still non-negligible) execution time, and I realized it wasn't worth all the effort when I only have a limited number of items that have three values. I'm just going to have the second and third fields always be a single string. But I hope someone can benefit from the script.

Comment: You are right about the `path` expression - although it's not mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#PATH), numeric key names should be escaped.